# JavaScript validation, prevent duplicate input fields

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with 10 Select Lists all have the same items. The items are populated from a PHP/MySQL array. The user needs to select one item per select list. I need to prevent the user from selecting the same item twice before submitting the form.

```
function checkDropdowns(){
    var iDropdowns = 10;  

    var sValue;
    var aValues = new Array();
    var iKey = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= iDropdowns; ++i){
        sValue = document.getElementById('test' + i).value;
        if ( !inArray(sValue, aValues) ){
            aValues[iKey++] = sValue;  
        }else{
            alert('Duplicate!');
            return false;
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? (No one will write code for you on SO), unless maybe you show you've given some effort :p

Comment: 10 select lists with the same items.  If they are in the same order, then they will have the same indexes.  How can you check to make certain that none of the selected indexes are the same?

Comment: Check the indexes of each list. Although personally I'd consider removing the item from the following lists to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @DaveNewton +1 for the removing of the items... Better be userfriendly than lazy :)

Comment: use <option disabled>. when a <select> value is selected, loop through the other <selects> and disable the option. should be very easy, especially if they all have the same indices. when an option is disabled it is still in the drop down but typically greyed-out and un-clickable.

Comment: see my answer i did it took time but yea

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to add an event listener on the value change of the selects. That function would then loop through the selects taking the values into memory after having compared it to the values it had already. If the loop finds that the current select has an option that is already selected, put it back to default value and display a little message...

Or, still on a change event, take the value of the just selected item and remove all the items of this value in the 10 selects. So at the end the user will only have 1 choice, since he only sees the options he can choose. But be careful, if the user changes his mind on one select, make sure you add back the option you removed in the first place.

Option 2 is to be prefered as a user point of view, you will cause less frustration.

EDIT:
The code you are providing already does quite a lot... All you need now is something to revert the change if it is invalid:

```
var defaultValues = [];
function onLoadSelect(){//Please execute this on document load, or any event when the select are made available.
    var iDropdowns = 10;
    var iKey = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= iDropdowns; ++i){
        var sValue = document.getElementById('test' + i).value;
        defaultValues['test' + i] = sValue;  
    }    
}
```

Then, in your function's else, reset the value according to the defaults we have gathered:

```
else{
    alert('Duplicate!');
    document.getElementById('test' + i).value = defaultValues['test' + i];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, I see it is your first question here... Please, next time try some stuff before you ask, and show us what you did, it is going to be easier for all of us. Now, since you only pitched an idea, I have answered with mine. I can fix my answer if you update your question to something more useful :) And Welcome home

Answer (score 0):

I have written code, i think it can be improved but it works as you asked.

Put it in inside script tag under body so it loads after document.

Put id names of select/dropdown elements in id array.

Take a look: //took me 3 hours O_O

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/TK9aX/15/

`i think i need better strategy to approach programming.`

Comment: Note::: id names dont have to be in order or first,second... they can be named anything.

Comment: Muhammad. This code is awesome! I have a little issue though. The POST variable is blank when the form is submitted. Any ideas why?